# Can't use my installed NuGet package in code

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

I have installed NuGet package Miracle.FileZilla.Api in my VS project, but when I try to include it in my code via directive "using" VS says there's no namespace "Miracle". How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: How did you install the package?

Comment: @MattiPrice I installed it in VSCode through NuGet Package Manager and it added this line in my .csproj file: "<PackageReference Include="Miracle.FileZilla.Api" Version="3.2.0"/>". Then I switched to the Visual Studio and it also says that I have package installed. But for some reason I can't include it in my code.

Comment: I'm guessing it's related to switching from VSCode to VS. If you try and just build the project anyway does it give you an error?

Comment: @MattiPrice I created new project in VS and installed package in it and it worked, thanks:)

Comment: Microsoft doesn't make the "NuGet Package Manager" extension in VS code, so I don't know how it works, but you need to do a `dotnet restore` after changing NuGet dependencies to that NuGet can make the packages available to the compiler and IntelliSense. If you used `dotnet add package ..`, it's automatic. It's also automatic when you build, so doing either should have made the namespace available in your original project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I have installed NuGet package Miracle.FileZilla.Api in my VS project,
>   but when I try to include it in my code via directive "using" VS says
>   there's no namespace "Miracle". How do I fix it?

The **main issue** is that the VS Code tool level like `nuget package manager` is too low to be used in a more advanced VS IDE. And thanks to **Matti** for the tips and information that make this question much simpler.

VS Code is a lightweight code editor and can install many extensions for development environment tools, such as compiling, installing nuget packages, publishing, etc.It has wide compatibility with projects, including Java. But tools are not powerful enough to use in some other areas.And it is more suitable for code editing.

VS IDE is a powerful integrated development environment and includes many of the tools of the development process, such as compiling, debugging, publishing, and so on. It is better suited to developing an entire project lifecycle.

**In brief**, due to the powerful function of tool in VS IDE and wide compatibility of projects in VS Code, nuget package in VS IDE can be used in VS Code and in turn, the errors occurs. Or please install nuget packages and develop projects in the same version of VS.

**Solution**

**1)** Please install nuget packages and then use it in the same VS version. **And l recommend you use VS IDE which is powerful enough.**

**2)** Or you should create a project and then install the nuget package in VS and then migrate it to VS Code, you can include it in my code via directive "using" without any errors.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't require the use of VS? VS isn't free, while VS Code is, so this isn't a viable answer for some folks.